# How to automatically refresh Stream Builder

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

**I have a stream builder calls a future function.
I need the stream builder to update automatically but it only gets refreshed when I close and reopens the app what should I do please give me a solution.
MY CODE:**

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: _databaseService.fetchNames(uid, 'Users').asStream(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        print(snapshot);
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(secondaryColor),
              )),
            );
            break;
          case ConnectionState.active:
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(secondaryColor),
              )),
            );
            break;
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.data == 'No data') {
              return Container(
                child: Center(child: Text('No Chats')),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.data != 'No data') {
              List names = snapshot.data['collection'];
              return ListView(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                children: names
                    .map((e) => ListTile(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => ChatScreen(
                                      username: e['name'],
                                      receiverUid: e['id'])));
                        },
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        title: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                          child: Text(
                            e['name'].toString()[0].toUpperCase() +
                                e['name'].toString().substring(
                                      1,
                                    ),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                          ),
                        )))
                    .toList(),
              );
            }
            break;
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return Container(
              child: Center(child: Text('No network')),
            );
            break;
        }
        return Container(
          child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(secondaryColor),
          )),
        );
      },
    )
```

My Future Function:

```
Future fetchNamesId(documentName, collectionName) async {
    Response response = await post(url,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        },
        body: jsonEncode(
            {"documentName": documentName, "collectionName": collectionName}));
    if (response.body == "No data") {
      return "No data";
    }
    return jsonDecode(response.body);
  }
```

This is the data I get stream i.e sanpshot.data:

```
{collection: [{id: 7hgIFK07xwhDGM82kJiQyGua36E3, name: bvc}, {id: Fgtf4ikE0QPifgknq5AVUdxCV2V2, name: vee}, {id: GbYWYJXcKwMmjsbx99QCvw0gWVL2, name: luu}, {id: egkH6fX7B2db54V1ALYWbKAXwG33, name: dia}]}
```

Whenever I add another value in my database the stream is not getting refreshed automatically I need to close and reopen the tab.

**In the code, I have made it asynchronous but even though it is not getting updated automatically.**

Please give me a solution I am struck.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the connection to your database is a one-time request. Your app is unaware of any changes on the server. It  I think you can do a couple of things:

1. Use a service such as Firebase Firestore that will push the updates to your app "automatically"
2. Implement web sockets in your app. You would need to implement web sockets on your server as well
3. Contact the server yourself every x minutes with a loop (Easy to implement, but not recommendable as it can be a drain on your users' device battery life)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a Provider. You can wrap you StreamBuilder to a StreamProvider like so:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<whatever your stream returns>.value(
      value: your stream,
      child: StreamBuilder(...
```

Comment: No, it is not refreshing automatically. What should I do can you explain clearly. It only shows the new values when I close and reopen the app I need it to happen without closing and reopening the app automatically.

Comment: Can you share how you receive your stream data and maybe I can help.

Comment: Like @Marthijn said you only fetch it once. I don't know how you can turn this into a stream tbh but if you do so, your app will listen for changes in your database. An easier solution would be to use Cloud Firestore as your database. In that case, it is easy to fetch streams.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.